# recomended Handlebar versions

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is there a list somewhere showing the recommended versions of Handlebar to use with each of the Emberjs versions?

The hyperlinks on the Ember website have Ember 1.31 with Handlebar 1.2.1.  The Handlebar website has version 1.3 as the most up-to-date download, which I've been using since Ember 1.2.  Should I move back to Handlebar 1.2.1 for Ember 1.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

The version tested with the release is the one expected to work correctly.

That being said it doesn't mean the future version of Handlebars won't work with it, but if a breaking change were to occur you may get yourself in trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Handlebars 2.0 is recommended version for ember.js

Comment: Can you include a source for that?